# Why do mobiles phones have non removable batteries at all?

Tags: batteries, mobile

Doesn't a removable battery have a lot of advantages over a non removable battery?
In case the phone drops in water/the battery gets faulty due to whatever reason, we can always change the removable batteries and voila, problem solved!

why do manufacturers produce phones with non removable batteries at all? is there some significant benefits of having a non removable battery over a removable one?

Comment: When you do not know what it is about then it is about money (or sex, or both sex and money).

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question.

Comment: @AlBundy - Is there a difference?

Comment: @NickAlexeev, how exactly is this question a 'rant' i.e. a temper-base outpouring? It's a fair question and should not have been put on hold, please release it. There is no reason that the answers can only be opinion-based.

Comment: Answer:   So the phone is always available for use as a GPS tracker or a handy microphone, wherever you go.

Comment: @SDsolar Yes, as was demonstrated on the show, 60 Minutes, some months back. A US representative's (senator, I think, but I'm unsure) cell phone was used by some researchers in Germany to fully monitor every word of his phone calls, grab his entire contact list and contact history, locations of travel, etc. All without his being able to tell (he was told, prior to the day, that this would be happening and when.)

Comment: Precisely, @jonk.   That can't work reliably if you could remove the battery from iPhones.

Comment: @NickAlexeev it is no rant; it is a simple question because i don't understand the point of it.. i wonder if you did answer the question anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the battery is removable. I've replaced batteries on iPods and iPhones. All you have to do is pry in the right places to open the case. (Be sure to use the right tools if you care about scratches.) There are instructions for doing this online.

When non-removable batteries were first introduced in mobile phones, they were controversial. But the advantages ultimately won out. You don't need a battery compartment or cover, and you don't need the battery to be in a protective shell. That lets you design a thinner, lighter, cleaner-looking phone. I don't know if they actually do this, but it should also be possible to integrate some of the protection circuitry into the charging circuit on the phone's mainboard, saving space and (probably) money.

Many (most?) of the people who buy high-end smartphones replace them every two years, at least in the U.S. (Our carrier contracts support this.) Those people normally don't need to replace the battery because it doesn't have enough time to wear out. So it's not much of a burden. And customers seem to be okay with battery life dropping over time.

Obviously, non-removable batteries also fit right in with the larger marketing goal of getting people to replace their phones often.

Answer (score 3):

Cost... and you sell more phones since the life is now limited. But in reality there is a significant cost involved in making the case such that you can remove the battery.

The manufacturer also does the math and considers the life expectancy of the battery vs the life expectancy of the unit itself. With the fast paced improvements in phone generation coupled with the much longer life of modern batteries it came to a point where battery replacement became more or less an obsolete requirement and unnecessary expense.

If you then add to that the cost of supporting distribution of the batteries themselves, which are often custom to the product, it ends up being cheaper to just give the user with the defective battery a new phone.

However, the fact that you can not actually turn the phone off completely, is a worry-some trend.

Comment: Or you make money through an exorbitant dealer-only replacement service...

Comment: I like the addition that you cannot keep the NSA (or sophisticated commercial interests or other gov'ts, either) from using your cell phone for purposes you don't know about and would not approve of, if you did. My wife, just last week, has decided to never again buy an advanced CPU-based device that doesn't also include a user-friendly way to completely remove its power source. So +1 for that.

Comment: @jonk Who's to say they don't use the RTC battery? =P

Comment: @DerStrom8 It won't power transmission (or reception) for long. That's assuming they could pull any serious current, at all (that's not easy, either, without an additional capacitor somewhere.) :) They might get a quip or two, though, if lucky.

Comment: Oh, but you forget that the government is hiding their technology from us. They have really ultra-low-power transceivers built into the phones that can run off the coin cell indefinitely. You actually think they'd expose that technology to the masses? ;)

Comment: "ultra-low-power transceivers" ? CMOS, at ultralow-power, has horrid noise floors. Thus nothing works. And the carrier will wander all over the assigned channel, as phase noise accumulates. ..... solution? Use a square foot of aluminum foil, place the suspect FBI-sponsored cell/smart phone in the middle, and fold/crimp the foil edges to exploit that excellent aluminum-oxide dielectric in forming short circuits at the crimp points, enclosing the phone in a no-exit-path Faraday cage.